# Microphone diaphragm displacement

Tags: forces, waves, acoustics, displacement

I recently read an [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_microphone) on a laser microphone, where an entire window pane is used as a microphone diaphragm.

It got me thinking, exactly how much does an object move when it's exposed to somebody talking.

For example, if I had an object that weighed x grams, had a surface area of y square meters facing the sound source, and the sound source was normal talking (40-60dBa)?

Comment: Is this not the kind of question you could have a go at yourself, no offence but it kinda seems like it, the only thing missing is the stiffness of the material.

Comment: A precursor to the device was used in a famous Soviet spy case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Theremin#Espionage